# Should gain of this differential circuit be absolute value?

Tags: differential-amplifier

Content is from the book *Design of Analog CMOS Integrated Circuits* (https://electrovolt.ir/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Design-of-Analog-CMOS-Integrated-Circuit-2nd-Edition-ElectroVolt.ir_.pdf) on Page 112.

Due to a manufacturing error, in the circuit of Fig. 4.19, \$M_2\$ is twice as wide as \$M_1\$. Calculate the small-signal gain if the DC levels of \$V_{in1}\$ and \$V_{in2}\$ are equal.

[image]

The following is my analysis. Since it's symmetrical, we can use virtual ground to analyze this circuit:

[image]

First, we only analyze the left part with KCL:

$$ -\frac{V_{out2}} {R_D} = V_{in} g_{m1} + \frac{V_{out2}} {r_{o1}}$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{V_{out2}} {V_{in}} = -g_{m1} (R_D \parallel r_{o1})$$

Now we only analyze the right part with KCL:

$$ -\frac{V_{out1}} {R_D} = -V_{in} g_{m2} + \frac{V_{out1}} {r_{o2}}$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{V_{out1}} {V_{in}} = g_{m2} (R_D \parallel r_{o2})$$

We combine this two equation into one:

$$\frac {V_{out2} - V_{out1}} {2 V_{in}} = -\frac{1}{2} (g_{m1} + g_{m2}) R_D$$

Since \$g_{m2} = 2 g_{m1}\$
$$\frac {V_{out2} - V_{out1}} {2 V_{in}} = -\frac{3}{2} g_{m1} R_D$$

But the book said:

$$|A_v| = \frac{2 R_D} {1/g_{m1} + 1/ g_{m2}} $$
$$|A_v| = \frac{4} {3} g_{m1} R_D$$

Comment: Your calculation seems correct but the result is wrong because you cannot split the circuit like that as it's not symetric. The voltage vgs of M1, M2 in this case are not same magnitude as you drew.

Comment: @internet What should you use to analyse this circuit?

Comment: You can always draw the small signal model to calculate gain but for this circuit I can do it in my head.
Assume that you use T model for the mosfets and ignore the output impedance.
`id1  = (Vin1 - Vin2)/(1/gm1 + 1/gm2)
Vout = Vout1 - Vout2 = id1*RD - (-id1)*RD  = 2id1*RD  = 2RD(Vin1 - Vin2)/(1/gm1 + 1/gm2) 
So Vout/(Vin1-Vin2) = 2RD/(1/gm1 + 1/gm2) = 4/3*gm1*RD with gm2 = 2*gm1`

Comment: @internet Could you please show me the small signal circuit diagram to make it easier to understand you equation?

Comment: check this: https://yourimageshare.com/ib/fqwo6Yy3wO

Comment: I also prefer the T-model. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/536586/why-does-a-circuit-model-of-n-mosfet-exhibit-a-finite-resistance-between-source/536639#536639  Using it we can see by inspection that the asymmetrical voltage gain is  **RD/(1/gm1 + 1/gm2)**, and if **gm2 = 2*gm2** we have  **2/3*gm1*RD** Thus, for differential output (Vout1 - Vout2) the gain will be twice this value the value  **4/3*gm1*RD**

Comment: @G36 Is symmetrical valid in this case?

Comment: Do you have in mind your method (grounding the M1 and M2 source)?

Comment: @G36 the source of M1 and M2 are virtual  grounded if it's symmetrical.

Comment: But this is not the case here. We do not have virtual GND because gm1 is not equal to gm2. So the middle point will not be at 0V. And this is why your method does not give the correct result. Using your method  we have the M1 gain **RD/(1/gm1)** and M2 gain is **RD/(2 * gm1)** and the overall  differential gain is **3*gm1*RD**

Comment: That's a bizarre manufacturing error. I know it's just a textbook example but I'm struggling to imagine how any problems at the manufacturing stage could alter the width of one transistor and not another!

Comment: @internet Could you please have a look at my answer. What's wrong here?

Comment: @G36 Could you please have a look at my answer. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is my analysis.

[image]

Firstly, we analyse the left part of this circuit with the use of KCL.

$$- \frac{V_{out2}} {R_D} = (V_{in1} - V_p) g_{m1} + \frac{V_{out2} -V_p} {r_{o1}}$$

$$\Rightarrow - V_{out2} (\frac{1} {r_{o1}} + \frac{1} {R_D}) = 
V_{in1} g_{m1} - V_p (g_{m1} + \frac{1} {r_{o1}})$$

$$\Rightarrow V_p = \frac{V_{in1} g_{m1} + V_{out2} (\frac{1} {r_{o1}} + \frac{1} {R_D})} {g_{m1} + \frac{1} {r_{o1}}}$$

Secondly, we analyse the right part of this circuit with the use of KCL.

$$ \frac{V_{out1}} {R_D} = -(V_{in2} - V_p) g_{m2} + \frac{V_p -V_{out1}} {r_{o2}}$$

$$\Rightarrow  V_{out1} (\frac{1} {r_{o1}} + \frac{1} {R_D}) = 
 - V_{in2} g_{m2} + V_p (g_{m2} + \frac{1} {r_{o2}})$$

We could substitute \$\frac{V_{in1} g_{m1} + V_{out2} (\frac{1} {r_{o1}} + \frac{1} {R_D})} {g_{m2} + \frac{1} {r_{o2}}}\$ for \$V_p\$ from what  we previously got.

$$\Rightarrow  V_{out1} (\frac{1} {r_{o1}} + \frac{1} {R_D}) = 
 - V_{in2} g_{m2} + \frac{V_{in1} g_{m1} + V_{out2} (\frac{1} {r_{o1}} + \frac{1} {R_D})} {g_{m1} + \frac{1} {r_{o1}}} (g_{m2} + \frac{1} {r_{o2}})$$

Since we already assume \$g_{m1} r_{o1} \gg 1\$ and \$g_{m2} r_{o2} \gg 1\$

$$\Rightarrow  V_{out1} (\frac{1} {r_{o1}} + \frac{1} {R_D}) = 
 - V_{in2} g_{m2} + \frac{V_{in1} g_{m1} + V_{out2} (\frac{1} {r_{o1}} + \frac{1} {R_D})} {g_{m1}} (g_{m2})$$

$$\Rightarrow  V_{out1} (\frac{1} {r_{o1}} + \frac{1} {R_D}) = 
 - V_{in2} g_{m2} + V_{in1} g_{m2} +  V_{out2} (\frac{1} {r_{o1}} + \frac{1} {R_D}) \frac{g_{m2}} {g_{m1}}$$

$$\Rightarrow  V_{out1} (\frac{1} {r_{o1}} + \frac{1} {R_D}) - V_{out2} (\frac{1} {r_{o1}} + \frac{1} {R_D}) \frac{g_{m2}} {g_{m1}}=  V_{in1} g_{m2} - V_{in2} g_{m2} $$

We also assume \$r_{o1} \gg R_D\$ and \$r_{o2} \gg R_D \$

$$\Rightarrow  V_{out1} (\frac{1} {R_D}) - V_{out2} (\frac{1} {R_D}) \frac{g_{m2}} {g_{m1}}=  V_{in1} g_{m2} - V_{in2} g_{m2} $$

$$\Rightarrow  (\frac{1} {R_D}) (V_{out1}  - V_{out2} \frac{g_{m2}} {g_{m1}})
=  V_{in1} g_{m2} - V_{in2} g_{m2} $$

For third equation.

$$- \frac{V_{out2}} {R_D} = \frac{V_{out1}} {R_D}$$

$$\Rightarrow - V_{out2} = V_{out1} $$

Substitute \$-V_{out2}\$ for \$V_{out1}\$

$$\Rightarrow  (-\frac{1} {R_D}) V_{out2} (1 + \frac{g_{m2}} {g_{m1}})
=  g_{m2} (V_{in1}  - V_{in2}) $$

The gain will be

$$\frac{V_{out2} - V_{out1}} {V_{in1} - V_{in2}}
=
\frac{2 V_{out2}} {V_{in1} - V_{in2}}
=
\frac{2 g_{m2}} {-\frac{1} {R_D} (1 + \frac{g_{m2}} {g_{m1}})}
$$

$$\frac{V_{out2} - V_{out1}} {V_{in1} - V_{in2}}
=
- \frac{2 R_D g_{m2}} {(1 + \frac{g_{m2}} {g_{m1}})}
$$

As we all know \$g_{m2} = 2 g_{m1}\$

$$\frac{V_{out2} - V_{out1}} {V_{in1} - V_{in2}}
=
- \frac{2 R_D g_{m2}} {(1 + 2)}
=- \frac{4 R_D g_{m1}} {3}
$$

Comment: @internet Could you please have a look at my answer. What's wrong here?

Comment: @G36 Could you please have a look at my answer. What's wrong here?

Comment: @Hearth Could you please have a look at my analysis?

Comment: Hi @kile, I only came across this by chance--you can't @-ping someone who hasn't already commented on the same post, so none of us got notifications for this. I'm afraid I don't have the energy or focus to go through this analysis on my day off, though.

Comment: It would be much simpler if you ignore ro1, ro2 at the beginning. I haven't checked your equations but if you need to solve for the general cases, you should write one more KCL equation at node Vp. So now, you would have three equations and three variables `Vp, Vout1, Vout2` to solve.

Comment: @internet Why would I need third equation? There is only one unknown variable \$V_p\$? What's the third equation look like?

Comment: We need three equations because we have three unknowns. You cannot solve it using only two.

Comment: @G36 Please take a look at my equation