Resistance in the small signal model of a MOSFET
I have a question about the small signal model of MOSFET. As you know there is a voltage-controlled current source in the model.  I've seen somewhere in books that we can replace it with a resistor with r=1/gm and the cause they provide for that, was since the voltage across current source is VGS and the current is gmVgs we can replace it with v/i = vgs/gmvgs =1/gm resistor.
How we say the voltage across current source is vgs since only 1 pin of it is common with VGS and another one is connected to the drain? The voltage of the current source is a little ambiguous for me.


Take a look here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/536586/why-does-a-circuit-model-of-n-mosfet-exhibit-a-finite-resistance-between-source/536644#536644  any additional question?

Thanks for that, but in my mentioned question, I meant Pi equivalent circuit as figure shows, and I think that answer couldn't  answer my question directly.

You cannot replace a dependent current source with a 1/gm resistor in a normal situation. You can do it only when you connect the MOS gate directly with a drain terminal (diode-connected MOS). Then you will end up with Vgs = Vds and Req  = (1/gm) || ro

Aha, that is a great point , I got my answer now. Thank you!
